# Custom keystroke button on Ubuntu dock or panel

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, .desktop, panel, ubuntu-dock

With a touchy laptop in mind, and also a physical keyboard with some missing buttons (like, delete, caps lock, etc.),
is it possible to create custom launchers, or panel indicators that can perform certain keystrokes?
Specifically Copy, Cut, Paste, Delete, and perhaps some others.
I know custom launchers can be made and assigned to application
But is a keystroke also possible?
GNOME extensions should have such a thing, but alas.
So I don't mind making the custom launcher, which seems easier.

Comment: Tx for the advıce. So far, so good. I dıd read somewhere that xdotools wont functıon ın wayland. But ın the normal sessıon, the launchers do work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simulate a keyboard shortcut using `xdotool` and thus create an application launcher for the shortcut and pin it to the dock. Install `xdotool` by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

and then follow the steps bellow for example for a copy action:

1. Create a simple `.desktop` launcher file, say `copy-this.desktop`, in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You can do that by running the following in Terminal

   ```
   touch ~/.local/share/applications/copy-this.desktop
   ```
2. Open the created file using a text-editor,  for example by running

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/copy-this.desktop
   ```
3. Add the following lines to this file and save it

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Copy This
   Comment=Copy selection
   Exec=xdotool key ctrl+c
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Icon=edit-copy
   ```
4. Click "*Activities*" or "*Show Applications*" and search for "Copy This". It should appear.
5. Right click and add to favourites.

Clicking this icon on the dock would simulate pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You can similarly create ones for other shortcuts.